# UIControlEventEditingChanged doesn't get fired when used parallel with delegate method shouldChangeCharactersInRange of UITextfield

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, uitextfield

I am facing problem in getting event of `UIControlEventEditingChanged` of textfield.

Here is code:

```
[_txtNum1 addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

then this method:

```
 -(void)textFieldDidChange :(UITextField *) textField{}
```

This is calling `textFieldDidChange` perfectly, when i don't implement textfield's below delegate method:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{
```

When i use delegate method `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` of textfield parallelly, it not getting event fired for `textFieldDidChange`, and only getting event for `shouldChangeCharactersInRange`.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set

```
 self.textfield.delegate = self;
```

change method won't be called if this method returned NO

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: i have already set _txtNum1.delegate=self;
and i am also getting event for delegate method shouldChangeCharactersInRange.
i am not just getting event for '-(void)textFieldDidChange :(UITextField *) textField{}' method.

Comment: ok, i got it, i have returned NO from shouldChangeCharactersInRange. that was making problem.

Answer (score 1):

@DhavalBhimani I have just create new app and take one textfield and assign delegate to that. just copy your code and paste it in my demo. it seems like its working. you can check below code. maybe you miss something..

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [_txtDemo addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
}

-(void)textFieldDidChange:(UITextField *)textField
{
    NSLog(@"called");
}

#pragma mark - textfield methods

-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSLog(@"string = %@",string);
    return YES;
}
```

> 2018-03-24 00:27:35.292771+0530 Demo Objective C[783:14964] string = h
>
> 2018-03-24 00:27:35.382728+0530 Demo Objective C[783:14964] called
>
> 2018-03-24 00:27:39.851133+0530 Demo Objective C[783:14964] string = i
>
> 2018-03-24 00:27:39.869326+0530 Demo Objective C[783:14964] called

Comment: thanks for answer, i got the problem, i was returning NO from delegate method, that was making problem.